# ASP.NET Master Pages in VB>NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

I have an asp.net website with individual .aspx files which all inherit my Custom Class. There are common features to each .aspx page such as menus and things like that. So I have created a Master Page.

I want to put the common methods which call methods from my custom class in my master page code behind and I cannot. As I don't seem to be able to get my Master Page to inherit from it.

I want to change the following..

```
Partial Class modules_MyPage
Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage
```

To something like this...

```
 Partial Class modules_MyPage
Inherits MyCustomClass
```

The above damages my content pages. I was wondering if anyone could advise me on the right approach.

Comment: Which class does **MyCustomClass** inherit from?

Comment: The Inheritance goes on for a while. MyCustomClass inherits from something that in turn inherits from something else and so on. Its not very well made. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is something like this:

```
Partial Class modules_MyPage Inherits MyCustomClass
```

where

```
Partial Class MyCustomClass Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage
```

but this isn't possible if your class already inherit from web.ui.Page

really usefull [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21294/Creating-a-Better-Master-Page)